# ATOM Linter error running PHP | Ошибка расширения на ATOM

Tags: php, atom

Возникла такая проблема:

[image: Ошибка]

В консоли было много ошибок, а в GOOGLE ничего на RU не нашёл. На EU краем глаза заметил фикс данной ошибки в пути. Если у вас LocalHost и у вас возникла такая проблема, тогда ответ будет ниже.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем скрипте PHP вы вставляете:

```
print_r($_SERVER['PATH']);
```

И смотрите путь где у вас установлен PHP модуль.
В моём случае на OpenServer 'e это был:

```
D:\ProgrammFiles\OpenServer\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\php.exe
```

В итоге вы просто подставляете этот путь в настройки расширения Linter:
[image: Пример]